# Parsing JSON with fastJson in C#

Tags: c#, json

I could not find an answer in the existing threads for my problem. I have this JSON string:

```
{
    "Count": 4,
    "Result:000": {
        "Score": 4.571,
        "W0DateTime": "2014-08-28 23:00:00",
        "W0Value": 1.0164,
        "W0Fibonacci": 0,
        "Direction": "SHORT",
        "StartDate": "2014-08-29 16:30:00",
        "EndDate": "2014-08-28 01:00:00",
        "BarsCalculated": 80
    }
}
```

How do I get the content of `Result:000`?

I have this code:

```
...
    public Dictionary<string, object> dictionaryObject;

    public void jsonInitStructure(string sJsonString)
    {
         dictionaryObject = (Dictionary<string , object>) fastJSON.JSON.Parse(sJsonString);
    }
...
```

`Count` is easy: `Convert.ToInt32(dictionaryObject ["Count"])` but how do I get the values from `Result:000`? For example `(Score, StartDate, EndDate, ...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried casting it?

```
var result000 = (Dictionary<string, object>)dictionaryObject["Result:000"];
var result000Score = Convert.ToDouble(result000["Score"]);
```

Comment: Perfect Rawling! This works exactly the way I wanted it! Thank you a lot for your help. It seems so unbelievable simple when I read it but I was not capable to find out on my own this cast!

Answer (score 0):

Plese have a try...

```
Array objList = (Array)dictionaryObject["Result:000"] ;
foreach (object obj in objList)
{
    Dictionary<string, object> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    dictionary = (Dictionary<string, object>)obj;

    var var1 = dictionary["Score"].ToString();
    var var2 = dictionary["W0DateTime"].ToString();

 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This does not work. This error is thrown: Object of type "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]" cannot be converted to type "System.Array". But Rawling's solution works perfectly! Again Thnx!